# Prevent users from clearing Firefox history

Tags: windows, firefox, parental-controls

As a parental control, I'd like to disable the ability to clear the history in Firefox.

Also, how can I have this history be automatically sent to my e-mail address?

Comment: And, if they use [Private Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Private-Browsing), what will you do then? You'd want parental control with a scope beyond just a single program such as Firefox. You'd be better off with software that monitors or logs network activity.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into a 3rd part parental control program for the emailing of history reports.

Otherwise, Windows 7 has a parental control feature built in.  You can read more about it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-Parental-Controls)

Answer (score 2):

You might be happier using your router's firmware to track history and email the logs to you. The browser history is too easy to defeat with portable apps, registy hacks, etc.

Most routers support this feature. If you want to be prescriptive about it, use [OpenDNS FamilyShield](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/security/3421701/get-free-web-filtering-with-opendns-familyshield/): set your router to use 208.67.222.123 and 208.67.220.123 as your DNS hosts.